# How to remove a special character pattern in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string name s,

```
String s = "He can speak English and Sinhala.[1]He<ename> has edited 12 CSE Staff Research Publications.[1][2]"
```

I want to remove `[1]` and `[1][2]` from the string. Note that we can have any number within the square brackets and any no of square brackets(like `[number][number][number]...`). I tried using this,

```
String removedNoTag = s.replaceAll("[\\[0-9\\]]","");
```

Yes it removes all [number].. patterns. But it also **removes all numbers within the text**(It removes `12` also).

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it removes any instance of a character that is either a number or a bracket.

replace with : `\\[[0-9]+\\]`

Answer (score 3):

try with this: `String removedNoTag = s.replaceAll("\\[\\d+\\]","");`

Answer (score 3):

You are escaping the wrong brackets in your regular expression. What you are looking for is:

```
String removedNoTag = s.replaceAll("\\[[0-9]+\\]","");
```

or

```
String removedNoTag = s.replaceAll("\\[\\d+\\]","");
```

With `\d` being the "short form of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your *outer* brackets define a set of characters to remove. That set is defined as `[`,`]` and `0-9`. So any combination of those is detected (for example `[]`, `2`, `]`, `[3]`, `[324]`, `]1[[[`).

Instead try `\\[\\d+\\]`, which means the open bracket, one or more digits (`\d`) and a closing bracket.